# Multiple rows data into multiple columns in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Product Variant.

```
sequence   No   item 
  400      1    4.5
  500      1     0
  501      1     0
  502      1     0
  503      1    B-DP
  504      2     0
  400      1    2.5
  500      2     0
  501      2     0
  502      2     0
  503      2    B-PP
  504      2     0

  My Required output  is :

  sequence  No  item  item1
  503      1    B-DP   4.5
  503      2    B-PP   2.5
```

I am trying but not coming as expected.. Can anyone suggest me on this please.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Go on. Show us what you tried.

Comment: Please explain the logic for transforming the data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select max(case when item like 'B%' then sequence end),
       no,
       sum(try_convert(numeric(38, 6), item1))
from t
group by no;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, 
need to use conditions as item like 'B%' and sequnce IN ('500','501','502','503','504')
because there will be lot of sequences among those need to take five sequences ('500','501','502','503','504')
and the logic for item1 is like if sequence = 400 then item should come..

Comment: Do i need to use sub queries to get the output.. please help me.

Comment: @rajini . . . On the data you have provided in the question, this should return the results that you specify.